# Invoke-vmscript fails to execute with unexpected error occurred on a receieve

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

Running below command on linux machine and it fails with below error:

```
Invoke-VMScript <<<<  -VM $machine.Name -ScriptType Bash -GuestUser $UserName -GuestPassword $Password -ScriptText $cmd -ToolsWaitSecs 400
```

Error:

```
Invoke-VMScript        The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-VMScript], ViError
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Client20_VmGuestServiceImpl_DownloadFileFromGuest_DownloadError,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.InvokeVmScript
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disconnect and connect back to VI server, this should fix the problem.
Disconnect-VIServer -Server  * -Confirm:$false -Force
Connect-VIServer -Server $vcIP -Protocol https -User $vcUser -Password $vcPW